# LWC - Jest test for Apex calls in wired function

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, mock

We have a class that calls the `getRecord` uiAPI and then using the result makes an APEX call to get more details from another custom object.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/ApplicationController.getData';

const FIELDS = ['A.some_filed__c']

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {


    // get progress bar config from account id
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$Id', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({error, data}) {
        if(error) {
            this.error = error
        } else if (data) {
            getData({ configId: data.fields.some_data__c.value })
            .then(result => {
                //some code
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error
            });
        }
    }

}
```

We have this jest test for this:

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/ApplicationController.getData';
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

// mock data for rendering progress bar
const mockStepListRecords = require('./data/getStepListRecords.json');
const mockStepListNoRecords = require('./data/getStepListNoRecords.json');
const mockAccountRecord = require('./data/getAccountRecord.json');
const getRecordWireAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getRecord);

// Mocking imperative Apex method call
jest.mock(
    '@salesforce/apex/ApplicationController.getData',
    () => {
        return {
            default: jest.fn()
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }
);

describe('c-progress-bar', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }

        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    function flushPromises() {
        return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
    }

    describe('getStepList @wire data', () => {
        it('renders progress bar with steps', () => {
            const element = createElement('c-progress-bar', {
                is: ProgressBar
            });
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            getRecordWireAdapter.emit(mockAccountRecord)

            return flushPromises().then(() => {
                getData.mockResolvedValue(mockStepListRecords)
                const stepEls = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(
                    '.progress-bar__step'
                );
                expect(stepEls.length).toBe(mockStepListRecords.length);
                expect(stepEls[0].getAttribute('data-id')).toBe(
                    mockStepListRecords[0].Id
                ); 
           });
        });

    });
});
```

We tried `Promise.resolve()` but event that doesn't work. We get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined



      18 |             this.error = error
      19 |         } else if (data) {
    > 20 |             getData({ configId: data.fields.some_data__c.value })
         |             ^
      21 |             .then(result => {
      22 |                // some code
```

We have mocked `getData` but for some reason it cannot find it. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What API version and Jest version are you using? Also, are you experiencing this from any other test suites?

Comment: following issue on [github](https://github.com/salesforce/wire-service-jest-util/issues/25) was opened for this and it is a known bug being fixed.

Comment: @raj Did you get this resolved after the Github issue was merge? If so, it'd be useful to put that as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer to help other.

Comment: I am having the same issue when I am calling imperative apex in Wired Function. @TrevorBliss

Comment: @DeepSinghal Can you verify you're on version 2.4.2 (or higher) of `@salesforce/wire-service-jest-util`?

Comment: Did anyone resolve this issue?